# Spring MVC recovering page state after saving

Tags: java, maven, session, spring-mvc, state

I have a Spring MVC application where I sometimes have to add a new object to a list, and at some point, save the page. At every point where I need to add something to a list, a controller action is called and when it is done adding it returns the page. The state of the page then is lost. (ie. scrollbar position). I would like to preserve the page state, also after saving the page (which does a redirect to the new page)

Right now I am putting some variables in the session, and reading them out EVERY time. I find this quite ugly.

Does anyone know like a solution to this? Or any third party dependency which can make my life easier on this? :)

Thanks in advance.

Ps. I hope my question is clear, and not too abstract. If so, I will try to clarify it more.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the complete page refresh is to use ajax.  Submit the new `List` item via an ajax request and the browser will not perform the full refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Exists another variant. You may perform AJAX call to Controller method and send only the data you need to save. After that through @ResponseBody annotation you can return refreshed data or any other result. So this solution force you to use AJAX call. You may use JQuery for this purpose.